# When should you, and should you not, add someone on Linked In?

Tags: professionalism, linkedin, networking

I'm wondering what kind of considerations one should apply when adding people on Linked In.

For example, if starting a new job, would it be normal add your new colleagues on Linked In?

Or would it be more a matter of adding colleagues when you leave a job, as to stay in touch?

Is there any general advice around this?

Not a duplicate of [LinkedIn invitations from people I don't know](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/3183/linkedin-invitations-from-people-i-dont-know) as it's about Linked In interactions with people you work with.

Comment: I am tempted to flag this question as a trivial question.

Comment: @AakashM I don't think it's a duplicate but as currently worded it's opinion-based. Geekrunner if you could edit to change it from a question where you're asking people "what should and shouldn't I do?" it might be on topic.

Answer (score 3):

First, figure out what is your intention in having this list on LinkedIn. Is this merely to be a group of people that you know or worked with in the past? Is this to be a concentrated group of co-workers that you want to stay in touch and know well? Set up an intention before moving onto the other stuff. There are more than a few possible ones here.

In starting a new job, depending on the intent it may or may not be normal. If you are merely collecting names and they're OK with that then you could try to add them as remember there is something to be said for the other person accepting the connection here. On the other hand, for some people, they would rather you worked with them directly for at least a few months before adding them.

Answer (score 2):

Before I add anyone to my Linkedin, I always analyse the relationships strength. If I started a new job, I would wait a few months to establish a relationship with my colleagues. I prefer quality over quantity with my connections.